# Tricky trigonometry question

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all solutions of the equations $\tan(3\arccos{x})=11/2$

I got $x = \cos(\frac{1}{3}\arctan(11/2) + n\pi/3)$

Which gives $6$ unique values of $x$, but only $3$ of them seem to work when I sub them in using my calculator. How do I know which $3$ values of $n$ to pick?

Comment: $\cos(A+B)$ helps??

Comment: My problem is that I'm confused about what to choose for n.

Comment: $x = \cos(\frac{1}{3}\arctan(11/2) + n\pi/3)$ This is what I meant to post - I got 6 unique values of x, but only 3 of them seem to work when I sub them in using my calculator. How do I know which 3 values of n to pick?

Comment: oh.. now it s becoming tricky :D.. let me try

Comment: @OliverBel : if you improve your question, as you seem to have done in your comment, you should edit the _question_, not just leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Let $\arccos x=\theta\implies 0\le \theta\le\pi$  and as the [Principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of $\cos$ lies in $\in[0,\pi]$

So, the problem becomes $$\tan3\theta=\frac{11}2$$ and as $$\tan3\theta=\frac{3t-t^3}{1-3t^2}$$

$$\implies 2t^3-33t^2-6t+11=0\  \  \  \  (1)$$ where $\displaystyle t=\tan\theta$

Solve $(1)$ for $\displaystyle t$

If $\displaystyle t=\tan\theta\ge0, \theta=\arccos x$ will lie in $\in[0,\frac\pi2]$

If $\displaystyle t=\tan\theta<0, \theta=\arccos x$ will lie in $\in(\frac\pi2,\pi)$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: It is straight forward. Exploit trig identities to at first get it into cos from tan:

$  cos(x)= 1 / sqrt(1+tan^{2}(x) ) $

then apply

$ cos(3 t) =  4 cos^3 (t)- 3 cos (t) $

Find solution, including its negative one as for arccos with other co-terminal angles.  This will give two roots. With negative sign of sqrt another two roots will be obtained.Divide all solution angles by 3.

Answer (score -1):

Have you covered the general solutions to trigonometric equations? For example, consider the general solution to $tan A = 11/12$. Tan is a positive number (in this case $+11/12$) in the first and third quadrants.

So, the general solution is $A = tan^-1(11/12) +k\pi = 0.74 radians + k\pi$. k is any integer.

But $A = 3cos^-1 (x)$.

So, $cos^-1(x) = 0.18 radians + k\pi/3$

Can you go on from here?